# Отслеживание действия garbage collector в java

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора

Есть ли какой нибудь способ отслеживать в программе действия garbage collector? например писать в логи все его похождения. вот он запустился, прошелся по классу, что затронул? young/old и пр. типы памяти.

Comment: Посмотрите https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/how-to-programmatically-obtain-gc-information. Возможно это то, что вам нужно

Comment: да похоже на то

Comment: Прекрасно. Удачи!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы можете включить логирование сборок мусора передав JVM параметр `-Xlog:gc*` при запуске программы.